# How to get a part from the full path in C#?

Tags: c#, string, directory

I have a full path as given below.

```
C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd
```

How can the DTDs "part" to be fetched from this whole part?

Desired output:

```
C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug‌​\DannyGoXuk.DTDs
```

Can I use `String`'s methods for this?
If yes, then how to fetch it?

Comment: Please write the output that you want from this example.  It sounds like you want the file name, but you are saying "directory".

Comment: Or perhaps there should be a \ where there is a . after DTDs?

Comment: i added a DTDs directory in DannyGoXuk project which contain all the files.

Comment: Shouldn't the path then be

C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk\DTDs\xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what it is exactly you want. Is the string above (C:\...) a directory name, or a file name? And which part do you want, everything from thebeginning until the last Backslash, everything from the last backslash to the end, or  something in between? Or do you want to extract a relative path?

Comment: i want the path till DTDs directory.i.e
string dirPath = C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk.DTDs

Comment: Your example path can only be split in 'C:\Users\\(...)\bin\Debug\ (Directory from the path) and DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd (file name). You could use the directory name and concatenate 'DannyGoXuk.DTDs'.

Comment: fyi, I've updated my answer again and I want to be sure you see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Please read the OP’s question and all of her comments carefully before downvotiong this. The OP’s title question isn’t EXACTLY what she wanted. My answer gave her what she needed to solve her problem. Which is why she voted it the answer. Yes, Joel’s answer is correct if specifically answering the title question. But after reading her comments, you’ll see that not exactly what she was looking for. Thanks.

Use this ...

```
string strFullPath = @"C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd";
string strDirName; 
int intLocation, intLength;

intLength = strFullPath.Length;
intLocation = strFullPath.IndexOf("DTDs");

strDirName = strFullPath.Substring(0, intLocation); 

textBox2.Text = strDirName;
```

Comment: Thanks JimDel but this part gave me the o/p 
" DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd ".
I am just looking for DTDs.
I dont want the file xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd with it.

Comment: the use this Substring instead...

strDirName = strFullPath.Substring(0, intLocation);

Comment: Put your file in c:\DTDsFolder\Sources\.... and you'll see this script crashing...

Answer (score 75):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` for the entire path, or `new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.Name` for just the name of that one folder.

---

**There is no directory named "DTDs" in the path you posted.**  IT looks like there's a *file* named `"DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd"`, but the periods (.) in that path are not valid directory separator characters.  Did you mean `"DannyGoXuk\DTDs\xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd"`?

If that's the case, *given that entire new path*, you want something like this to return a list of files in the `DTDs` folder:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk\DTDs\xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd";
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.GetFiles();
```

---

> in properties window i choose Build Type as Embedded resource.

And now we finally get to it.  When you choose "Embedded Resource", the item is bundled into your executable program file.  *There is no direct path anymore*.  Instead, set your Build Type to "Content"  and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".

Comment: GetDirectoryName("C:\Mehrdad\Test") returns "C:\Mehrdad"

Comment: Joel,you are getting me wrong.In solution explorer in VS2008 i created a folder named DTDs under dannyGoXuk prj and kept all my files in it.Then in properties window i choose Build Type as Embedded resource.Now wen i try to get the  Full path of those files i get the whole path as i posted above.
but i want the path till directory DTDs.i hope i m able to clear..

Answer (score 12):

Calling

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName
```

with the full directory path returns the last part of the path which is a directory name. `GetDirectoryName` returns the whole path of parent directory which is unwanted.

If you have a file name and you just want the name of the parent directory:

```
var directoryFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\DTDs\mydtd.dtd");  // C:\DTDs
var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryFullPath);  // DTDs
```

Comment: GetFileName() would return "mydtd.dtd"

Comment: GetFileName given the directory path will return the last part. You should call it with the *directory path*, which you can get from GetDirectoryName. I explained it in the edit.

Comment: I misunderstood that you were doing a two step process-thought you were calling GetFileName() on the original string.

Comment: No it does not help, i am geeting the files from resources and these files are in DTDs folder under DannyGoXuk Project.so i am fetching these files one by one using foreach loop and want to get the directory DTDs.But all of the above  and below answers does not help.

Comment: @crazy_itgal: Given the path you mentioned in the question, what exactly you need as output?

Comment: i want the path where DTD file is there.for example 
 string path = C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk\DTDs
i want this "path"...

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) to get the directory from the full file path:

```
Directory.GetParent(path).FullName
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( fullPath ) )
```

That will return just the name of the folder containing the file.

For

```
C:\windows\system32\user32.dll
```

this will return

```
system32
```

I'm inferring that that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Harpo u are somewhat close to my answer but here u have directory separator to get "System32" as directory but in my case there is no such "/" thing. Whereas i have files from resources and these files are in DTDs folder under DannyGoXuk Project.so i am fetching these files one by one using foreach loop and want to get the directory DTDs.Which is just given by DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd.where xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd is a dtd file in the DTDs directory under DannyGoXuk project.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath).name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) ...

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(myStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string manipulation directly. Instead use `GetDirectoryName` of the Path class:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the FileInfo object...

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd");
string directoryName = info.Directory.FullName;
```

The file doesn't even have to really exist.

Comment: i am getting this error..
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' 
Because i am using the files in resources.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetDirectory` on the path you have specified returns:

"C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug"

Try it yourself:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Users\Ronny\Desktop\Sources\Danny\kawas\trunk\csharp\ImportME\XukMe\bin\Debug\DannyGoXuk.DTDs.xhtml-math-svg-flat.dtd");
```

Your question is a little strange though- there is no directory called DTDs.

Comment: Directory DTDs is in project DannyGoXuk.i have embedded all the resource files in the DTDs directory.In the code i want to fetch this directory how to do it,this only i want to know? Thanks..